# Showing multi selected values with same name

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to show multi checkbox values after selecting them in form, but I'm able to show only the last selected value instead of multiple selected values. How can I show all the selected values?

This is my views.py

```
def multi(request):
if 'hobbies' in request.GET and request.GET['hobbies']:
    hob = request.GET.getlist('hobbies')
    for h in hob:
        message = 'You entered ..... %r' % h
else:
    message = 'enterd wrong datails'
return HttpResponse(message)
```

My template is

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body  bgcolor='#455772' >
<form action="/multi/" method="get">
Hobbies:<input type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='football'/>football <input      
type='checkbox' name='hobbies' value='cricket'/>cricket<input type='checkbox'    
name='hobbies'value='others'/>others<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def multi(request):
    if 'hobbies' in request.GET and request.GET['hobbies']:
        message = ','.join(request.GET.getlist('hobbies')) 
    else:
        message = 'enterd wrong datails'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: will u please guide me how to insert into sqlite3 db. im very new to jango plz help

Comment: Sorry, I'm little bit busy right now. I have only time when it's saturday and sunday. There are many tutorials online, search for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
hob = request.GET.getlist(u'hobbies')
```

Comment: "UnboundLocalError at /multi/
local variable 'message' referenced before assignment                             Exception Location:views.py in multi, line 19 "                                     im getting this error after that correction                                  thank u so much for your help,plz guide ..........

Comment: yes i have edited with that notation but facing error like this                                                      "Key 'hobbies[]' not found in <QueryDict: {u'hobbies': [u'football', u'cricket']}>"

Comment: its showing me last selected one , not all the values which i selected  :)

Comment: take a look at [this post](http://www.djangofoo.com/93/request-post-get-multiple-values) may be helps you

Comment: this is for your learning or job i think you are new to Django